# Sort items on a page by specified criteria

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'd like to be able to sort content on my webpage by different criteria (for example: by price and name).

I would like the outcome to be exactly this: http://www.pccasegear.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=7

I'm using static html, the list of items is not being called to the page in any way and I do  not wish o use a database of any kind.

The code I'll be using will be similar to this:

```
<div class="product">
  <div class="name">
    <p>Product 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    <p>$1.00</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code so far.

Comment: If the page is static with a fixed number of products, you could store the product information in an array of Product objects, sorting them as desired, and printing them by index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to `sort` by `price`

```
$('div.price').map(function () {
   return {val: parseFloat($(this).text(), 10), el: this.parentNode};
}).sort(function (a, b) {
   return a.val - b.val;
}).map(function () {
   return this.el;
}).appendTo('body');
```

**Demo** [Sort by price](http://jsfiddle.net/5k5bL/)

After some `modification` you can `sort` it by `name` also like,

```
$('div.name').map(function () {
   return {val: $.trim($(this).text()), el: this.parentNode};
}).sort(function (a, b) {
   return a.val > b.val;
}).map(function () {
   return this.el;
}).appendTo('body');
```

**Demo** [Sort by name](http://jsfiddle.net/5k5bL/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much, this does exactly what I wanted.